# Determine if a string contains a sequence of numbers

Tags: php, integer, substring, sequence

Say I have an integer `88123401`, and I want to determine whether it includes a sequence of numbers like 1234, 23456, 456789, or the like of any length and from any beginning of numbers.. Is this possible at all in PHP, and if so, how would one go about finding out?

Comment: you can use [regular expressions](http://php.net/book.pcre)

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem, could you please show us what you have tried?

Comment: I have tried looking at both substrings and regular expressions, but I am unsure how one would go about determining this exact issue.

Comment: @SahilM Not a homework problem. Trying to develop a function that can determine the value of a phone number. :)

Comment: I think the best way to go about this is to loop over all the characters in the string, then have an inner while that checks for a sequence from that character onwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some function with a for so you go through all the string comparing each character with its predecessor.

```
function doesStringContainChain($str, $n_chained_expected)
{
    $chained = 1;

    for($i=1; $i<strlen($str); $i++)
    {
        if($str[$i] == ($str[$i-1] + 1))
        {
            $chained++;
            if($chained >= $n_chained_expected)
                return true;
        }else{
            $chained = 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

doesStringContainChain("6245679",4); //true
doesStringContainChain("6245679",5); //false
```

Answer (score 2):

use a loop and use the answer of @jtheman

```
$mystring = '88123401';
$findme   = array(123,2345,34567);
foreach ( $findme as $findspecificnum ) {
    $pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

    if ($pos === false) {
        echo "The sequence '$findme' was not found in the number '$mystring'";
    } else {
        echo "The sequence '$findme' was found in the number '$mystring'";
        echo " and exists at position $pos";
    }
}
```

keeping it easy and straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Treat the number as a string and search with `strpos()`.

Example:

```
$mystring = '88123401';
$findme   = '1234';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);


if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The sequence '$findme' was not found in the number '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "The sequence '$findme' was found in the number '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: Would there be a more efficient way to go about handling all different sequences? `123`, `2345`, `34567` etc?

Comment: You might be able to using a clever regex, but I'm not qualified enough to give the best answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
$number = "88123401";

$splittedNumbers = str_split($number);
$continuous = false;
$matches[0] = '';
$i = 0;

do {
    if ((int)(current($splittedNumbers) + 1) === (int)next($splittedNumbers)) {
        if($continuous) {
            $matches[$i] .= current($splittedNumbers);
        }
        else {
            $matches[$i] .= prev($splittedNumbers) . next($splittedNumbers);
            $continuous = true;
        }
    } else {
        $continuous = false;        
        $matches[++$i] = '';
    }
    prev($splittedNumbers);
} while (!(next($splittedNumbers) === false));

print_r(array_values(array_filter($matches)));
```

This lists all the matches that are sequential in an array. We can process further based on the results.

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1234
    [1] => 01
)
```